# Java Nested For loops run time analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, analysis

Say I have the following for loops:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i*=2) {
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j*=2) {
        //constant functions here
    }
 }
```

The outer loop will run `log(n)` times, my question is about how many times the inner loop will run. We can approximate `j` to be 2<sup>s</sup>, for some `s`, and it will stop when 2<sup>s</sup> < i, which can again be approximated to 2<sup>r</sup>, for some `r`. If we take the log of both sides, we get that s < r, which is when the second for loop will stop. Based on this, can we say that the inner loop runs constant times? And that the total number of times this function will run is just `log(n)`?

Comment: i=0, so it will become a infinite loop as i*=2 always become 0

Comment: sorry, my mistake about the starting values for i and j. Fixed so they both start at 1 now.

Answer (score 0):

First neglect the outer loop, suppose the value of i =4, the inner loop will run for log(4) times, generalizing the inner loop will run log(i) times,for different values of i. Now consider the outer loop, value of i changes log(n) times. Hence the complexity is log(n)*log(i) or just simply (log(n))^2

Answer (score 0):

in one word the answer is : **Log<sub>2</sub>(n)<sup>2</sup>**

**Proof**

consider **Log<sub>2</sub>(n) = k** so we have in first iteration of outer loop, inner loop runs `1` time because `i = 2`, in second iteration inner loops runs `2` times because `i = 4`, and ... in k'th iteration of outer loop, inner loop runs `k` times because i = 2<sup>k</sup> so number of your iterations:

```
1 + 2 + ... + k = k(k+1)/2
```

so the answer is **O(Log<sub>2</sub>(n)<sup>2</sup>)**